# Powershell, using contains to check if files contain a certain word

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script which looks through all files and folders under a given directory it then changes all instances of a given word in .properties files to an instance of another given word.

What I have written below does this however my version control notices a change in every single file regardless of whether it contains an instance of the word to change. To counter this I tried to put in a check to see whether the word is present or not in the file before I get/set the content (shown below) however it tells me that [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Contains'. I assumed this meant that $_ was an array so I tried to create a loop to go through it and check each file at a time however it told me it was Unable to index into an object of type System.IO.FileInfo.

Could anyone please tell me how I could alter the code below to check if ever file contains the wordToChange and then apply the change it it does.

```
$directoryToTarget=$args[0]
$wordToFind=$args[1]
$wordToReplace=$args[2]

Clear-Content log.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter *.properties -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 


If((Get-Content $_.FullName).Contains($wordToFind))
{
    Add-Content log.txt $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) | 
     ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $wordToFind , $wordToReplace } | 
     Set-Content $_.FullName
}



}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that you are loading the file twice, consider loading into variable and doing -contains and -replace against the variable, might run a bit quicker...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$directoryToTarget=$args[0]
$wordToFind=$args[1]
$wordToReplace=$args[2]

Clear-Content log.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter *.properties -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 

$file = Get-Content $_.FullName
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $wordToFind}
If($containsWord -contains $true)
{
    Add-Content log.txt $_.FullName
    ($file) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $wordToFind , $wordToReplace } | 
     Set-Content $_.FullName
}

}
```

This will put the content of the file into an array `$file` then check each line for the word. Each lines result (`$true`/`$false`) is put into an array `$containsWord`. The array is then check to see if the word was found (`$True` variable present); if so then the `if loop` is run.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. On a side note can you think of a reason why the .properties filter would not fully work. It's still looking at .sh files even though it's not making any changes

Comment: So your just looking for files with the exstention `.properties`? If so that filter should work fine...

Are you getting the expected files listed when you type the `Get-ChildItem` on its own into the PowerShell shell (`Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter *.properties -Recurse`)?

Comment: Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871147/find-specific-string-in-textfile-powershell/41871326) which has another way to go about it which fit my case more simply.

Answer (score 4):

Simplified contains clause

```
$file = Get-Content $_.FullName

if ((Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match $wordToFind}) -contains $true) {
    Add-Content log.txt $_.FullName
    ($file) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $wordToFind , $wordToReplace } | 
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: I would advise to use Foreach-object instead of the alias: % in examples as it will be easier to understand for everyone.

Comment: I agree but this is a "simplified" answer

Answer (score -1):

**The simplest way to check that file contains the word**

If we are looking at `Get-Content` result we find *string System.Array*. So, we can do like in System.Linq in .NET:

```
content.Any(s => s.Contains(wordToFind));
```

In PowerShell it looks like:

```
Get-Content $filePath `
            | %{ $res = $false } `
               { $res = $res -or $_.Contains($wordToFind) } `
               { return $res }
```

As a result, we can aggregate it in cmdlet with params of file path and containing word and use it. And one more: we can use Regex with `-match` instead of `Contains`, so it will be more flexible.