# Tomcat servers webpages check using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tomcat, smtp, alert

Have a good working copy below.  I have also fixed the varibles to not be abbreviated.

However, under the Good section (just beyond the else), if there is a content issue, would like the content to also be checked three times.

If there is a web exception, it checks three (3) times correctly.  However, if the server is up and running there is no content checking if the string it is looking for is re-checked:

Re-writing this as requested for clarity, just before: catch [Net.WebException] I did try to write the part of what I am looking for, but could not get it to work.  I maybe incorrect in this as the [Net.WebException] may pick up the error handling for this.

```
            else
            {
                #BAD CONTENT
                if ($Retrycount -gt 2){
                    if (!(Test-Path "$($mypath)\$servern$flag")) {
                        "$(get-date -Format 'hh:mm, dd/MM/yyyy') - $($string)" | Out-File "$($mypath)\$servern$flag"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $servern ($ip) </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $Date </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $type </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $stringTest is not found </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
                        Write-Host $stringTest ' is not found'
                    }
                    # STOP LOOPING AND LETS GO TO THE NEXT COMPUTER OR QUIT
                    $Stoploop = $true
                }
            Write-Host "$RetryCount $servern is not up and running retrying in 10 seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
            $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
            }
        }
         $Stoploop = $true
    }
    catch [Net.WebException] {
```

WebCheck_computers.txt contains:

```
SERVER01,10.10.10.10,80,http://10.10.10.10/
SERVER02,10.10.10.11,80,http://10.10.10.11/
SERVER03,10.10.10.12,80,http://10.10.10.12/
SERVER04,10.10.10.13,80,http://10.10.10.13/
```

Now, let's show the current working code:

```
# http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/07/powershell-simple-retry-logic/
$mypath = "d:\WORK\ps";
$serverlist = "$($mypath)\WebCheck_computers.txt";
$fileName = "$($mypath)\webtest.htm";
$checkfile = "$($mypath)\chk.htm";
$stringTest = "have a good database connection";
$flag = "webtestflag.txt";

##########################################################################################################
### CLEAR FILES BEFORE STARTING

Remove-Item $fileName
New-Item -ItemType file $fileName -Force
New-Item -ItemType file $checkfile -Force

##########################################################################################################
### FUNCTIONS

Function writeHtmlHeader {
param($fileName)
    $date = (get-date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
    Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"
    Add-Content $fileName '<title>Webpage Health Report</title>'
    Add-Content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
    Add-Content $fileName  "<!--"
    Add-Content $fileName  "td {"
    Add-Content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "border-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "border-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "padding-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "padding-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "}"
    Add-Content $fileName  "body {"
    Add-Content $fileName  "margin-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "margin-"
    Add-Content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
    Add-Content $fileName  ""
    Add-Content $fileName  "table {"
    Add-Content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
    Add-Content $fileName  "}"
    Add-Content $fileName  "-->"
    Add-Content $fileName  "</style>"
    Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<body>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "<table width='100%' border='1'>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "<td colspan='4' height='25' align='center'>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Web Page Health Report - $date</strong></font>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName  "</tr>"
}

# Function to write the HTML Footer to the file
Function writeHtmlFooter {
    param($fileName)
    Add-Content $fileName "</table>"
    Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
    Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function sendEmail {
    param($htmlFileName)
    $from=New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "Support<support@company.com>"
    $to= New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "Support<support@company.com>"
    $subject="Server WebPage HealthCheck - $Date" 
    $smtphost="1.1.1.1"
    $body = Get-Content $htmlFileName
    $smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost
    $msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $msg.isBodyhtml = $true
    $smtp.send($msg)
}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader {
    param($fileName)
    Add-Content $fileName "</table>"
}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader {
    param($fileName)
    Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'>Server Name</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'>Time Test Started</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'>Web Request Type</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'>Web Page Result</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

##########################################################################################################
### SCRIPT
remove-item $fileName
writeHtmlHeader $fileName
writeTableHeader $fileName
#writeTableFooter $fileName
#writeHtmlFooter $fileName

foreach ($computer in Get-Content $serverlist) {
    $servern=$computer.split(",")[0]
    $ip=$computer.split(",")[1]
    $type = $computer.split(",")[2]
    $url = $computer.split(",")[3]
    $Date = Get-Date
    $servern
    if ($Computer -notmatch 'DB') {
        $Stoploop = $false
        [int]$Retrycount = "0"
        do {
            try {
                $w = New-Object net.WebClient
                $p = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy 'http://proxy:8080'
                $p.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
                $w.proxy=$p
                $w.DownloadFile($url,$checkfile)
                if (Test-Path $checkfile) {
                    ## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633666/powershell-using-contains-to-check-if-files-contain-a-certain-word
                    $file = Get-Content $checkfile
                    $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $stringTest}
                    If($containsWord -contains $true -and $stringTest -gt 3) {
                        #GOOD CONTENT
                        if (Test-Path "$($mypath)\$servern$flag") {
                            remove-item "$($mypath)\$servern$flag"
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #BAD CONTENT
                        if (!(Test-Path "$($mypath)\$servern$flag")) {
                            "$(get-date -Format 'hh:mm, dd/MM/yyyy') - $($string)" | Out-File "$($mypath)\$servern$flag"
                            Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
                            Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $servern ($ip) </td>"
                            Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $Date </td>"
                            Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $type </td>"
                            Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $stringTest is not found </td>"
                            Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
                            Write-Host $stringTest ' is not found'
                        }
                    }
                }
                 $Stoploop = $true
            }
            catch [Net.WebException] {
                # AN EXCEPTION WAS PREVIOUSLY FOUND - DO NOT NEED TO GO THROUGH ALL THREE TESTS
                if (Test-Path "$($mypath)\$servern$flag") {
                    $Stoploop = $true
                }
                # SERVER IS DEFINITELY OFF-LINE AND WE NEED TO GENERATE A REPORT
                if ($Retrycount -gt 2){
                    if (!(Test-Path "$($mypath)\$servern$flag")) {
                        "$(get-date -Format 'hh:mm, dd/MM/yyyy') - $($string)" | Out-File "$($mypath)\$servern$flag"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $servern ($ip) </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td align='center'> $Date </td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align='center'><font color='Yellow'> $_.Exception.ToString() </font></td>"
                        Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
                        Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
                        Write-Host $($mypath)\$servern$flag
                        Write-Host "$RetryCount $servern is not responding after 3 retries."
                    }
                # STOP LOOPING AND LETS GO TO THE NEXT COMPUTER OR QUIT
                $Stoploop = $true
                }
                else {
                    # LOOP COUNTER IS NOT DONE YET - KEEP GOING
                    Write-Host "$RetryCount $servern is not up and running retrying in 10 seconds..."
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                    $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
                }
            }
        }
        While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
    }
}

#writeHtmlHeader $fileName
writeHtmlFooter $fileName
$date = (get-date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
$file = Get-Content $fileName
##867
if ($(Get-Item $fileName).length -gt 1000) {
    sendEmail $fileName
}

##########################################################################################################
### SCRIPT IS DONE
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find what you're asking. Can you please narrow both the question and the provided code to the specific problem you're having?

Comment: You should avoid using abbreviated variable names (`$fl`, `$DT`, `$w`, `$p`), especially if you're not the one reading your code. Moreover, try to make the names as explicit as possible (`$str` > `$message`, `$DT` > `$date` > `$today`)

Comment: Just re-wrote the question part.  Also, updated the abbreviated variables as requested.