# Not publishing a SQL connection string on deployment when it already exists using Transforms

Tags: c#, tfs, webdeploy

TFS 2015, vNext build process (not xaml)

I'm trying to automate the deployment process for an MVC web app.  The servers that it would be deploying to have different SQL connection strings.  So my current deployment is to copy the web.config file to web.config.save manually, deploy the new version using WebDeploy then go to the old web.config.save file and copy over the connection string.  I'm to the size now where this is not going to be sustainable much longer.  So I need to automate this process further.  I've got TFS automatically building and deploying to my test server (which also has a different connection string so it's a great test).  In the "publish" properties, I tried deselecting the "Use This connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)" checkbox in the publish-settings-database section then checked in the project again to TFS.  But when deployed, the web.config took the default setting.  I don't want to remove this setting because I want a default connection string there for new installs.

I could write an xml transfer program to save off the current connection string then overwrite when complete again.  But I figured there must be a way to do this with the current tool set and why try reinventing the wheel?

I started down the path to use transforms.  So I created a web.config.release in VS2015 then added in this into the web.config.release file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="AppEntities"       connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBName.csdl|res://*/Models.DBName.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLExpress;initial catalog=DBName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So, does anyone know how I can make the SQL connection string update only if it doesn't exist in the current web.config for deployment?

Comment: Several information would help to answer your question: what do you mean with 'copy off'? where does the web.config.save file comes from? Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using a XAML build or vNext Build of TFS2015+ and VSTS?

Comment: Thanks, updated the questing to clarify your comments.

Comment: An associate told me about transforms then I found this article on the subject, it appears to work in my initial testing. http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this experience with TFS 2015 vNext build, 
in the 2Q of 2016 we assigned a Dev Ops person, who was really good with PowerShell, and he took ownership of the build and deploy process. Some of the things he came up with was a post build script.

Now to answer your question: For us, the Post-Build script would do the deployment part, and as part of the deployment you would update the connection string in the web.config. Now this would require someone in your team to become really good with PowerShell.

Now what I would do is write a special word in the original file like "{ConStringHere}", and the replace it with the Powershell script, that way you'll only replace it once.

See this how to verify if a file contains a word and replace it using PowerShell:
[Powershell, using contains to check if files contain a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634071/3360636)

I'll highlight some of the benefits we have encountered with this approach:

- You don't need a solution, project and classes to modify some files. Most post-build files modifications can be done in powershell with line or 2.
- You can keep the powershell scripts in TFS keeping a history and comments of the changes.
- You can have the special values (Connection Strings, users, passwords) defined as build variables that are easier to change and with higher security than hardcoded values in a project.
- You can have multiple scripts per environment. Ideally all scripts should be almost the same per environment, but maybe in production you are publishing to 2 different servers, so you'll need to call a line twice.
- You'll save developers time, since the person maintaining the powershell doesn't have to be a full stack developer.

Comment: It looks like the transforms are for only during compile.  I didn't do a powershell script, I could write this in C# in minutes so that's what I ended up doing.