# Find specific String in Textfile

Tags: powershell

I know this question might be a "new guy question" but I probably made a logical mistake.

I have a text file and I want to search if it contains a string or not. I tried it as shown below but it doesn't work:

```
$SEL = "Select-String -Path C:\Temp\File.txt -Pattern Test"
if ($SEL -eq $null)
{
    echo Contains String
}
else
{
    echo Not Contains String
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

i think this is what you are trying to do:

```
$SEL = Select-String -Path C:\Temp\File.txt -Pattern "Test"

if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
    echo Contains String
}
else
{
    echo Not Contains String
}
```

In your example, you are defining a string called `$SEL` and then checking if it is equal to `$null` (which will of course always evaluate to `false`, because the string you define is not `$null`!)

Also, if the file contains the pattern, it will return something like:

```
C:\Temp\File.txt:1:Test
```

So make sure to switch your `-eq` to `-ne` or swap your `if/else` commands around, because currently you are echoing `Contains String` when the `$SEL` is `$null`, which is backwards.

Check [SS64](http://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html) for explanations and useful examples for everything in `PowerShell` and `cmd`

---

Another way of checking if a string exists in the file would be:

```
If (Get-Content C:\Temp\File.txt | %{$_ -match "test"}) 
{
    echo Contains String
}
else
{
    echo Not Contains String
}
```

but this doesn't give you an indicaion of *where* in the file the text exists. This method also works differently in that you are first getting the contents of the file with `Get-Content`, so this may be useful if you need to perform other operations on those contains after checking for your string's existence.

Answer (score 20):

modify your quote string like this and use simplematch for dont use regex search and -Quiet for return a boolean and dont search in all file (better for performance)

```
if (Select-String -Path C:\Temp\File.txt -Pattern "test" -SimpleMatch -Quiet)
{
echo "Contains String"
}
else
{
echo "Not Contains String"
}
```

Comment: Please explain what was wrong, why and how it was fixed. That would be a good learning point for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but found a quicker solution for just testing if the string is in the file.

```
$SEL = get-content c:\temp\File.txt
if( $SEL -imatch "test" )
{
   Write-Host 'Contains String'
}
else
{
   Write-Host 'Does not contain String'
}
```

using Measure-Command, with a 1Mb file, this completed in 23ms, and the select-string was 44ms.  So if you're just looking to test, this is faster. Also, it returns the line(s) that contain the text, so that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The script below will do what you want:

```
$SEL = Select-String -Path c:\temp\File.txt -Pattern test

if( $SEL.Length -gt 0 )
{
   Write-Host 'Contains String'
}
else
{
   Write-Host 'Does not contain String'
}
```

Your line `$SEL = "Select-String ..."` actually declares `$SEL` as being a string - it does not instruct PowerShell to execute `Select-String`.